# How to iterate over 4 elements at a time in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this input for a program:
  `10 8
1 1 4 2
2 4 6 4 
4 2 5 0
4 3 4 5
5 2 6 1 
3 5 4 2
6 4 6 5
7 2 6 1`
Where the first 2  elements are an height and width and remaining are coordinates for points that make line segments.
and I have this method:

```
 public static String[] trees(int[] input) 
    {
        W = input[0];
        H = input[1];

        int x1, x2, y1, y2;

        for (int i = 2; i < input.length; i+=4) 
        {
            x1 = input[i];
            x2 = input[i + 1];
            y1 = input[i + 2];
            y2 = input[i + 3];

            StdOut.println(x1 + x2 + y1 + y2);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It's only a prototype but as of now I only want to iterate over the `input`array. I'm getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
Note: W and H are `int` classwide variables

Comment: You are getting out of bounds exception because your loop goes to input.length-1 but you are then trying to access input[i+3] with will be input[input.length + 2] with is 3 places over the end.

Comment: This means the array is not exactly 2 + 4 * n in length. Perhaps you are expected to use the width and height for something.

Comment: As @PeterLawrey said, your `input` is not the correct length. Proof: Running [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/genaOh) with your data. Check your assumptions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I have to use the height and width to do checks

Comment: @Andreas I'm a bit confused I've printed the array before and it had all the elements.. or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: @DarkInspiration Probably. ;-) You should add a guard check at the beginning of the method: `if (input.length % 4 != 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input length: " + input.length + " for " + Arrays.toString(input));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like below. Since you are adding i = i + 4, you need to traverse till the last 4 element.

```
 public static String[] trees(int[] input) 
{
    W = input[0];
    H = input[1];

    int x1, x2, y1, y2;

    for (int i = 2; i < input.length-3; i+=4) 
    {
        x1 = input[i];
        x2 = input[i + 1];
        y1 = input[i + 2];
        y2 = input[i + 3];

        StdOut.println(x1 + x2 + y1 + y2);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Changing to `length-3` makes no difference if `input.length` is 2 + 4 * n. The problem is that `input` does not contain what is expected.

Comment: @Andreas it will make the error go away, but it won't fix the input. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, but making the error go away, and not process the entire array, is wrong too. At least with the error, you know something is wrong, instead of silently processing the data incorrectly. In this case, error is your friend.

Comment: @Andreas agreed. The original code is better because it assumes the input has to be right.

Answer (score 0):

With this input provided there is no issue . index out of bound will occur for your case if your input come in such a way that you have less than 4 element in your coordinates set for eg input= {10,8,1, 1, 4 } - now this is a problem as inside your for loop you want i+3 which is obviously not available in your input.

Hope it helps!!